# Slicing string with Nordic letters in rust

Tags: rust, utf-8, ascii

What I am trying to do is to slice a string that has Nordic letters but it throws this error:

`'byte index 1 is not a char boundary; it is inside 'å' (bytes 0..2) of` å`'`

```
fn main() {
    let str = "äåö".to_string();
    println!("{}", &str[1..]);
}
```

Comment: You need to at least iterate over `chars` instead of bytes. But you should probably be using something like https://docs.rs/unicode-segmentation/latest/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes instead.

Comment: Your error does not fit to your code; it should be `it is inside 'ä'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
fn main() {
    let str = "äåö".to_string();
    let slice_position = str.char_indices().nth(1).unwrap().0;
    println!("{}", &str[slice_position..]);
}
```

```
åö
```

The problem here is that `str`'s indexing is in bytes, but it is UTF-8 encoded and `ä` takes more than one byte in UTF-8. So slicing at `1` actually cuts off half a character, which is a runtime error in Rust.

The reason `str` behaves this way is because you can't actually determine the position of the n-th character without iterating over the entire string. UTF-8 has variable-length characters, meaning, the position of a character depends on the previous characters.